# Barrier does not respect margin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

This is the first time I am using a `Barrier` and I am having trouble with the following requirements, considering an inner `ConstraintLayout` with 2 `TextView`s: the width of the `ConstraintLayout` must be as large as the widest `TextView` and a margin at the end of 5dp between the `Barrier` and the parent view.

Currently my view is looking like this: [image]

I don't know if the `Barrier` is applied well. I would suspect that the `Barrier` must be placed at the end and constrained to the parent's end as well. **That doesn't work, there is no margin at all.** This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF1A1A">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#28E313"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
                android:text="TextV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
                android:id="@+id/barrier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:barrierDirection="end"
                app:barrierMargin="100dp"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView2,textView3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="53dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```